# matching with comment in lex(flex) using ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compiler-construction, lex

i have a question about matching with comment and regular expression

i used "//".*$ ("" used because syntax error)

and action was just print yytext - printf(%s is comment",yytext)

but...

the output was so strange that i cant guess the problem.

input file is

[i want to extract comment. ;// or " "//](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZTQe.jpg)

and output was

[the problem was cut off yytext for comment..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jirVq.jpg)

for example

// Displays "Hello World!" String

was extracted just "Hello World!" String

where is gone // Displays.. .

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're including the newline in what you print. Depending on what you're printing on it may do strange things. Try `printf("%.*s\n", yyleng-1, yytext);`

Comment: wow!! so thank you! it works the way i thought!
why yyleng was used by the way ?